# Graph Distance of the Vertices of a Hypercube is Exponentially Bounded

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-explanation, combinatorial-geometry

Fix hypercube $\{ 0, 1 \}^n$. Let $A \subseteq \{ 0, 1 \}^n$ of size $|A| \geq 2^{n - 1}$. Then it is claimed $\forall t > 0$,
$$
|\{ \nu \in \{ 0, 1 \}^n: \mathrm{dist}_{\{ 0, 1 \}^n}(\nu, A) > t \}| \leq 2\exp\left( -\frac{t^2}{16n} \right).
$$
I am trying to follow this proof:

> Fix $f(\nu) := \mathrm{dist}_{\{0, 1\}^n}(\nu, A)$-is coordinate-wise $1$-Lipschitz.
> Hence if $X$ is uniform, random vertex of $\{ 0, 1 \}^n$, then through bounded difference inequality
> $$
> \mathbb{P}\{ |f(X) - \mathbb{E} f(X)| \geq t \} \leq 2\exp\left( -\frac{t^2}{4n} \right).
> $$
> Remains to note: $\mathbb{E} f(X) = O(\sqrt{n})$.

I am not very sure if I understood this proof: I follow everything until the last sentence. **How do we know $\mathbb{E} f(X) = O(\sqrt{n})$ and how does knowing $\mathbb{E}f(X) = O(\sqrt{n})$ help us to obtain the claim?**

Comment: First of all, I'm guessing $|\cdot|$ denotes measure rather than cardinality. Second, I think the constant in the big O will matter for deducing the claim. From the first thing I said, the claim is trivial if $t \le 4\sqrt{n}$, so we may suppose otherwise. If $\mathbb{E}f(X) < 2\sqrt{n}$, then $\mathrm{dist}_{\{ 0, 1 \}^n}(\nu, A) > t$ implies $|f(\nu)-\mathbb{E}f(X)| > t-2\sqrt{n} \ge  t/2$, so we may use the given bounded difference inequality with $t/2$ in place of $t$, which will give the claim. So, it just suffices to show $\mathbb{E}f(X) < 2\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: And this should follow from $|A| \ge 2^{n-1}$, but I don't see the argument immediately.